# Convert ISO format date time into a Date in mongoDB 3.6

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

`"dateField" : ISODate("2019-05-20T19:04:35.000Z")`

How to convert this into

`"dateField" : ISODate("2019-05-20T00:00:00.000Z")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert date to string using [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) *(Y-m-d)* and then convert to ISO date using [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/),

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      date: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: {
            $dateToString: {
              format: "%Y-%m-%d",
              date: "$date"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BsAZ00Tj28E)

Comment: if $date is null, the resultant doc will be having ```"date": null``` . Is there a way to avoid this. That will save the disk space as there are so many documents and date fields.

Comment: I do not want ```"date": null``` in the result. Do conversion only if the field is not null.

Comment: Unfortunately no! As this project stage is coming in the middle of aggregation just for couple of date fields.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/sd0w0SCoRD_  - the result should not have any date fields with null.

Comment: You can ask a new question, because this is good question, i will answer there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63374525/avoid-having-null-fields-in-result-when-using-datefromstring-on-a-field